# Why is the answer for small numbers wrong? with MPIR

Tags: c++, c, rounding, rounding-error

I'm using MPIR to deal with extremely small numbers. Somehow the answers I'm getting are wrong, and I have no idea why (something with rounding I guess..). How does rounding work in MPIR, and is it the reason for me getting these wrong answers?

Here is the code (the relevant part):

```
    long long a = 100000;
    mpf_class calc(p[i],500);
    cout << "p[i] = " << setprecision(32) << calc << endl;
    calc = 1-calc;
    cout << "1-p[i] = " << setprecision(32) << calc << endl;
    mpf_pow_ui(calc.get_mpf_t(), calc.get_mpf_t(), a);
    cout << "(1-p[i])^a = " << setprecision(32) << calc << endl;
    cout << "probLessThanR = " << setprecision(32) << probLessThanR << endl;
    calc = 1-calc-probLessThanR;
    cout << "1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR = " << setprecision(32) << calc << endl;
    if (calc>0)
        cout << "calc>0 = " << 1 << endl;
```

And here is the output for some values of p[i] and probLessThanR:

```
    p[i] = 2.0432284241450287639483056612667e-17
    1-p[i] = 0.99999999999999997956771575854971
    (1-p[i])^a = 0.99999999999795677157585705860637
    probLessThanR = 2.0432284241428158e-012
    1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR = 1.2561170838194078535224341399684e-25
    calc>0 = 1
    p[i] = 2.1679268932387850003127872242701e-17
    1-p[i] = 0.99999999999999997832073106761215
    (1-p[i])^a = 0.99999999999783207310676356492969
    probLessThanR = 2.1679268932410045e-012
    1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR = -4.5694136331284619232701251208227e-24
    p[i] = 2.2996656655640389938724454087815e-17
    1-p[i] = 0.99999999999999997700334334435961
    (1-p[i])^a = 0.99999999999770033433443860521077
    probLessThanR = 2.2996656655715272e-012
    1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR = -1.0132363051975571461595673730287e-23
    p[i] = 2.4388090428503683876184122197242e-17
    1-p[i] = 0.99999999999999997561190957149632
    (1-p[i])^a = 0.99999999999756119095715260547742
    probLessThanR = 2.4388090428370166e-012
    1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR = 1.0377918963850787511442329601381e-23
    calc>0 = 1
```

All the answers of `1-(1-p[i])^a-probLessThanR` should be positive. I prefer positive and less accurate than negative (but accuracy is really important).

Any Ideas?

Edit: added the output as a text and the value of a. BTW, a is long long for a reason (it can have bigger values).

Comment: Copy-paste your output instead of screenshooting it. This is rather annoying to read, some people may not have images enabled and cannot be used to quote (pieces) of the output in possible answers.

Comment: Edited and added what you asked for, thanks. long long a = 100000;

Comment: Maybe relevant: Denormalized Floating Point numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's correct.

Thanks ***so*** much for the screenshot. Much more artistic than a mere cut & paste. Who cares about usability after all?

If `(1-p[I])^a` is `0.99999999999783207310676356492969`

And `probLessThanR` is `2.1679268932410045e-12`

Then `probLessThanR` is `0.0000000000021679268932410045`

So using elementary school addition with carry:

`(1-p[I])^a + probLessThanR` is, where

```
      0.99999999999783207310676356492969 
    + 0.0000000000021679268932410045` 
    ~ 0.9999999999999999999999045684...
Carry                         1    1
    = 1.0000000000000000000000045694...
```

So `1-(1-p[I])^a - probLessThanR` is `0.0000000000000000000000045694...`. Which is what you have.

Comment: Oh about the screenshot I'm sorry. And also I realize now that my question was stupid. I used google's calculator to check what the real output should be. I will never do that again :\